# Detect undeclared variables in angular expressions

Tags: angularjs

How to detect all variables that are only declared inside an expression so I can then be able to ajax their value based on their name.

For example:

```
<div ng-controller='doController'>{{user}}</div>
<script>
  app.controller('doController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    dbUrl='http://mydata.com/'
    expvar=getExpressionVariables()  // returns ['user']
    $http.get(dbUrl+expvar[0]).then(function(response){
      $scope[expvar[0]]=response
    }
  }])
</script>
```

How could getExpressionVariables() work?

Comment: I'm very confused at what you're trying to do.

Comment: @tymeJV When a variable inside an expression is undefined I want to have the name of the variable and use it to retrieve it's value asynchronously from the web

Comment: I don't think you can do that...

Comment: @tymeJV Could you point me the way in the angularjs code where it evaluates the expressions?

Comment: I've figured out that angular finds all the variable names in html and stores them in expression array on interpolate function https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/1e58488ad65abf7031bab5813523bb9d86dbd28c/src/ng/interpolate.js#L236

Answer (score 0):

Angular Hint with the interpolation module answers the question but haven't yet been able to make it work 
https://github.com/angular/angular-hint-interpolation